# Get artifact outputs from batch-list in AWS codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a code pipeline building my artifacts through code build. I'm running into an issue where I have too many output artifacts and I'd like to parallelize my build steps speed it up anyways. I broke up my build scripts and added a base build script to run all of these in a build-list. The builds are running to completion but I can't seem to find any output artifacts. The artifact section in the aws console tab builds for the build is blank and I'm not seeing anything in my S3 bucket. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Build project:

```
BuildRunner:
Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
Properties:
  Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-BuildRunner
  Artifacts:
    Type: CODEPIPELINE
  BuildBatchConfig:
    ServiceRole: !ImportValue BuildExecutionRoleArn
    Restrictions:
      MaximumBuildsAllowed: 5
  Environment:
    ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM
    Image: aws/codebuild/standard:6.0
    Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
    EnvironmentVariables:
      - Name: BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKET
        Value: !ImportValue ArtifactBucketId
      - Name: S3_BUCKET
        Value: !ImportValue ArtifactBucketId
  ServiceRole: !ImportValue BuildExecutionRoleArn
  Source:
    Type: CODEPIPELINE
    BuildSpec: infrastructure/pipeline/buildspecs/build.yaml
```

Pipeline stage

```
- Name: Build
      Actions:
      - Name: Build
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Version: 1
          Provider: CodeBuild
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref BuildRunner
          BatchEnabled: true
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: SourceCode
        OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: uiBuild_uiBuildOutput
        RunOrder: 1
```

build.yaml

```
version: 0.2

env:
  shell: bash

batch:
  fast-fail: false
  build-list:
    - identifier: uiBuild
      buildspec: infrastructure/pipeline/buildspecs/ui-build.yaml
    # - identifier: apiBuild
    #   buildspec: infrastructure/pipeline/buildspecs/api-build.yaml

artifacts:
  files:
    - '*'
  secondary_artifacts:
    uiBuildOutput:
      files:
        - '*'
```

ui-build.yaml

```
version: 0.2

env:
  shell: bash

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - echo "installing base packages"
      - npm i

      - echo "installing packages"
      - npm run install:ui

      - echo "installing rust dependencies"
      - curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y
      - source $HOME/.cargo/env
      - rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
      - pip3 install cargo-lambda
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "building packages"
      - npm run build:ui

      - echo "packaging packages"
      - npm run package:ui

artifacts:
  files:
    - '*'
  secondary-artifacts:
    uiBuildOutput:
      base-directory: ui/www
      files:
        - '**/*'
    lambdaEdgeBuildOutput:
      base-directory: infrastructure/url
      files:
        - '**/*'
```

I'm assuming the problem is somewhere with my artifacts block but I'm not sure where and why.